# FlashCS4: dynamic text is not being contained within the text box

Tags: dynamic, textbox, flash-cs4, uicomponents

I have a dynamic text box which is of the size 300 x 300. However, when I load in text from an external file it just ignores this size and keeps on going vertically. The width remains the same which is fine. What I really want to do is use the uiscroller to go through the remaining text. Instead, the text just goes on past the bottom of the screen. This happens with or without the scroller. : /

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using a standard TextField, or a TextArea (*UIComponent*)? In both cases it shouldn't resize itself after assigning a text value though (unless you set `TextField.autoSize`). Can you show some of the code, or explain a bit better, what exactly you do/use?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I was autosizing it. I thought that had something to do with the scrollbar. Thanks a lot.